# UICollectionView reload collection background

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

How can I reload collection background?
I got dynamic item size and then I scroll back - I see lags on collection background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the trial and use [revealApp](http://revealapp.com) to debug your view.

Without code, or a clear question, i don't think anyone can answer.

good luck.